# Extending FOSUserBundle in order to have two type of users (two entities in two separate tables)?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to extend the FOSUserBundle so that I can handle two (or even more) types of users, that will share the common properties (like username and email, inherited from FOSUserBundle), and also have their own specific differences (that will live in different tables).

Can you suggest a way to implement the described requirements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to deal with this issue. With some help from Symfony community of course ...

I used the [PUGX](https://github.com/PUGX)/[PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle) that extends FOSUserBundle by adding the feature to handle users of different types. It's magic is based on the doctrine2 inheritance, so it currently only supports the ORM db driver (as described in bundle's documentation).

Great job PUGX,

Thanks!